# Looping over Dynamic Multi-dimensional Array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having difficulty with an multidimensional array. Here is a portion of the array. It's dynamic in that the top level array can have any number of elements and the child arrays, can have any number of elements as well. But each child array will contain the same amount of elements. If one child array has 16 elements, they will all have 16 elements, and if one has 20 elements, they will all have 20 elements.

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 25
        [3] => 38
        [4] => 50
        [5] => 63
        [6] => 75
        [7] => 85
        [8] => 88
        [9] => 100
        [10] => 113
        [11] => 125
        [12] => 138
        [13] => 150
        [14] => 163
        [15] => 175
        [16] => 188
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [1] => 48
        [2] => 37.22
        [3] => 52.56
        [4] => 63.17
        [5] => 74.45
        [6] => 87.98
        [7] => 96.11
        [8] => 98.36
        [9] => 111.67
        [10] => 132.20
        [11] => 146.87
        [12] => 160.85
        [13] => 174.39
        [14] => 187.70
        [15] => 203.04
        [16] => 215.90
    )
```

What I am trying to do is to extract the data in a format like:
ProductCode: [2][1][1][2], Width: [2][1], Height: [1][2], Price: [2][2].

Can someone point me in the right direction of how I can loop over this to extract the data like I need to?

Comment: **What have you tried?**

Comment: I'm confused about how you want the data extracted. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure, I need to pull 4 values for each record, a productcode, width, height, and price. The product value needs to be 1st element of the 2nd array concatenated with the matching child element in the 1st array, for example, element [2][1] matches to [1][2]. The width value would be [1][2], the height would be [2][1] and the price would be equal to [2][2]. The next loop would be product code [2][2] + [1][3], the width would be [2][2], the height would be [1][3], and the price would be [2][3]. And so on...

Comment: So [2][2] is both the price for the first product and the width for the second product?

Comment: [2][2] is the price and [2][1] is the width for the product.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a stored procedure in SQL 2008 to handle this instead of using PHP.